# when I print the array it only shows the last line from the txt file instead of the whole thing?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, text-files

this is my code that read from the txt file then addds its contents to an array with an index of 10
i want it to list all of the contents but it only lists the last one 10 time.

```java
String filePath10 = "src//SalmonSortingEfficiencies//10nums.txt";
String filePath10000 = "src//SalmonSortingEfficiencies//10000nums.txt";
String start;
boolean eof;
if (rBtn10.isSelected()) {
    try {
        String temp;
        String phrase;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath10);
        //opens the stream to the text file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //Reads the data in the text file
        eof = false;
        while (!eof) {
            start = br.readLine();
            if (start == null) {
                eof = true;
                // sets eof to true if the name is null/seeing
                // where the end of the file is so br stops reading
            } else {
                temp = br.readLine();
                int smallArrayNumbers = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                phrase = smallArrayNumbers + "\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    smallArray[i] = phrase;
                }
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e);
        //looks and prints out any errors found
    }
    for (String item : smallArray) {
        txtONumbers.append(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a for loop? You add the same value to the array 10 times.

Comment: to add every number in my text file until all 10 spaces are full

Comment: Every time you read a number, you fill the array with that number in the `for` loop. Remove that loop. Declare `int i = 0;` before the read loop. Then add it to the array with `if (i < smallArray.length) smallArray[i++] = phrase;`

Comment: You set the value of "phrase". Then you have a loop that adds that value to the array 10 times? Why are you doing that? You have the same value 10 times. You don't have 10 unique values.